# Pattern to match all lowercase letters in strings

Tags: lua

I am very new to patterns. I want to pick up the strings `jjjjj`, `ae`, and `hii`.

I would like to match all lowercase letters in each quoted group of characters.

```
Str = [["1jjjjj" "Wae1" "Uhi2i"]]
for X in string.gmatch(Str,'%".-[%l]([%l]*).-%"') do
    print(X) -- jjjjj, ae, hii
end
```

Comment: Please be clear and precise. In the test you say you want jjjjj and hii, but then in code you say you want to print jjj and i. What is it that you want?

Comment: I want to print all the lowercase letters of the word inside the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. One way to do it, at least:

```
local str = [["1jjjjj" "Wae1" "Uhi2i"]]
for word in str:gmatch("%S+") do    
    local lowercase = ""

    for char in word:gmatch("%l") do
        lowercase = lowercase .. char
    end

    print(lowercase)
end
```

Comment: Here you go. One way to do it, at least:    

    local str = [["1jjjjj" sjaj "Wae1" jaka "Uhi2i"]]
    for word in str:gmatch("%S+") do    
        local lowercase = ""

        for char in word:gmatch("%l") do
            lowercase = lowercase .. char
        end
        
        print(lowercase)
    end       //so it may be wrong, because it will take much more of the letter inside the "

Comment: Yes, that all sounds familiar ;) If it works for you, mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the lower case letters, you could *remove* the *non-lower case* chars.

```
xs = {"1jjjjj", "Wae1", "Uhi2i"}
for _, x in ipairs(xs) do
    lowers = x:gsub("%L", "")
    print(lowers)
end
```

```
jjjjj
ae
hii
```

I'm assuming you have the flexibility to use a table to store the strings, instead of having to parse out the quoted parts of a single string.